# Javascript window.location.href redirection not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Upon entering correct username/password, login success appears. I want to redirect to different page upon successful login, but window.location.href not working.

**index.html**

```
<form id="myFormlogin" action="login.php" method="POST">
    Email:
    <input type="text" name="usernamelogin" />
    <br />Password:
    <input type="password" name="passlogin" />
    <br />
    <button id="login">login</button>
</form>
<div id="ack"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["usernamelogin"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["passlogin"]));

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "login success";
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**script.js**

```
("#login").click( function() {

if( $("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "" )
      $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
    else
          window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `id` instead of `name`

chnage your code as

```
Email: <input type="text" id="usernamelogin"/><br />
Password: <input type="password" id="passlogin"/><br />
```

instead of

```
Email: <input type="text" name="usernamelogin"/><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="passlogin"/><br />
```

And use `return false` to prevent default action

```
$("#login").click(function () {
    if ($("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "")
        $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
    else 
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/SzhbM/

Comment: made no difference, same as before

Comment: @BaljeetSingh, see demo

Comment: It is working in the fiddle, but not on my desktop. I added the filename before the code. See if the problem is due to this. Actually i get login success (from login.php echo). Not anything from the my_script.js

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the form may be submitting.  Try preventing the default action of the form.

```
$("#login").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if( $("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "" )
        $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
  else
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";         

});
```

Comment: Form submits and i am getting the output from the php echo not from the jquery part, even with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap code inside `$(document).ready();` and also user `preventDefault` so it will execute only defined code.

**Example**

```
$("#login").click( function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
```

Also you are using `if( $("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "" )` this code but you forget to assign `ID` to the `input` fields.

And that is why jQuery was unable to find that two fields and stop executing script further.

You can check it in firebug.

**Comment Code Response**

Made below changes in **index.html** page.

```
<form id="myFormlogin" action="login.php" method="POST">
    Email: <input type="text" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" id="passlogin" name="passlogin"/><br />
    <button id="login">login</button>
</form>
```

what i did is added `name attribute` for the `input` fields.

**replace your mys_script.js with below code**

```
$(function()
{
    $("#submit").click( function()
    {
        if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#pass").val() == "" )
        {
            $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url         :   $('#myForm').attr('action'),
                data        :   $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success     :   function(info)
                {
                    $("#ack").empty();
                    $("#ack").html(info);
                    clear();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function clear()
    {
        $("form :input").each( function() {
            $(this).val("");
        });
    }

    $("#login").click( function()
    {
        if( $("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "" )
        {
            $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url         :   $('#myFormlogin').attr('action'),
                data        :   $('#myFormlogin').serialize(),
                success     :   function(info)
                {
                    $("#ack").empty();
                    $("#ack").html(info);
                    clear();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and finally make changes in your `login.php` file as below,

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["usernamelogin"] );
$password = mysql_real_escape_string( md5($_POST["passlogin"]) );

$sql="SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());   
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1)
{
    echo "found user";
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: @BaljeetSingh well i can not understand what you mean..? i see you are replacing html with static content so where from php code is echoing.

Comment: @BaljeetSingh it does not event alerting for login click handler in jquery code.??? if not then can you please share all script.?

Comment: upload it on 4shared or dropbox and send me link.

Comment: @BaljeetSingh see my updated answer i have added all the correction in edit

Comment: Have you noticed, when we click on login button leaving the username password fields blank, it is dispalying the "Wrong Username or Password" from login.php , But i want it to display "Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter." from the my_script.js (That is the main task). Also as i mentioned in the question the redirection not working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `ID` selector instead of `name`. so add ID in both input :

```
Email: <input type="text" name="usernamelogin" id="usernamelogin"/><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="passlogin" id="passlogin"/><br />
```

Then change function to :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click( function() {
        if( $("#usernamelogin").val() == "" || $("#passlogin").val() == "" )
            $("#ack").html("Username/Password are mandatory fields -- Please Enter.");
            return false;
        else
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";         
            return false;
    });
});
```

And set `return false` that will prevent default action.

Comment: I found one problem, whatever i do only php code echoes. (even after this)

Comment: You have add myscript.js file in main file ?

Comment: You have wrap your code `$("#login").click( function() {` inside `$(document).ready();` ?

Comment: see here, https://github.com/sandhus/phpImageMagic/blob/master/Registration/index.html